# Read response from Facebook Graph Request in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to add a Facebook friend list to my Swift iOS app using the Graph API.

I'm struggling to work out how to actually access the data that's being send back from Facebook.

The response I get looks like this:

```
success(FacebookCore.GraphResponse(rawResponse: Optional({
"first_name" = Jamie;
id = 1626917907360895;
"last_name" = McAllister;
name = "Jamie McAllister";
picture =     {
    data =         {
        height = 50;
        "is_silhouette" = 0;
        url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/12994335_1101318013254223_4481895970110564364_n.jpg?oh=d10209f113213981e4417e7f6f3f82d8&oe=5A91F135";
        width = 50;
    };
};
})))
```

My graph Request is just `/me` for now as I'm the only registered user. But all the fields in the response are what I will be requesting from the friends list

The graph request looks like this:

```
var graph = GraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me")
    graph.parameters = ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, name, email, picture"]

    graph.start({ (response, data) in
        print("======GRAPH=====")
        print(data)

        })
```

So, I want to be able to take the `GraphResponse`, make it an Array and assign it to a variable. I am completely stumped by this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read response from Facebook Graph Request use the below line of codes

```
let info = data as! [String : AnyObject]
 if info["name"] as? String != nil {
   self.usernameLbl.text = info["name"] as! String
 }
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: this wasn't my question.... I'm using "/me" because it will be the same information and I need something to use as test data. I don't know how to use the information I'm getting from the response (the `data` variable)

Answer (score 3):

Hope this Helps
**Swift 4.2**

```
    func getFbId(){
    if(AccessToken.current != nil){
        let req = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "email,first_name,last_name,gender,picture"], accessToken: AccessToken.current, httpMethod: GraphRequestHTTPMethod(rawValue: "GET")!)
        req.start({ (connection, result) in
            switch result {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)

            case .success(let graphResponse):
                if let responseDictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {
                    print(responseDictionary)
                    let firstNameFB = responseDictionary["first_name"] as? String
                    let lastNameFB = responseDictionary["last_name"] as? String
                    let socialIdFB = responseDictionary["id"] as? String
                    let genderFB = responseDictionary["gender"] as? String
                    let pictureUrlFB = responseDictionary["picture"] as? [String:Any]
                    let photoData = pictureUrlFB!["data"] as? [String:Any]
                    let photoUrl = photoData!["url"] as? String
                    print(firstNameFB, lastNameFB, socialIdFB, genderFB, photoUrl)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't working in 4.2 for me. signature for request.start appears to have changed

Answer (score 2):

The Graph request start completion block has changed to requiring 3 arguments instead of 2.

So you will have something like this (**NOTICE THERE ARE NOW 3 ITEMS PASSED IN THE START BLOCK** [connection, result, and error]):

```
let params = ["fields" : "email, first_name, id, picture"]
    let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
    graphRequest.start{
        (connection, result, error in

        if error == nil {
           if let responseDictionary = result as? NSDictionary {

            UserProfile.userName = responseDictionary["first_name"] as? String ?? "User"


           UserProfile.userID = responseDictionary["id"] as! String

           var pictureUrl = ""
           if let picture = responseDictionary["picture"] as? NSDictionary, let data = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary, let url = data["url"] as? String {
                                        pictureUrl = url

                                    }
                                }
        }else{
            print("error in graph request:", error)

        }
```